# Failing while testing autowired field using Junit

Tags: spring-boot, junit

Am new for Junit, any solution for below issue is welcomed.
I have a main class like,

```
@Service
public class MainClass extends AbstractClass {

@Autowired
ClassA a;

@Autowired
ObjectMapper mapper;

public void methodA(){
....
AnotherClass obj= (AnotherClass)mapper.readerFor(AnotherClass.class).readValue(SOME_CODE);
.......
}
```

Test Class is,

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({MainClass.class})
public class MainClassTest {

@Mock
ClassA a;

@Mock
ObjectMapper mapper;

@InjectMocks
MainClass process = new MainClass();

//I have to do somthing for Autowired mapper class of main in test class as well

@Test
public void testProcessRequest() throws Exception{
    process.methodA()
}
```

Am getting null for mapper object in main class while testing, Yes am aware that I haven't dne any kind of initialization.
Is there a better way for writing the junit mapper.
Note : I tried @Mock for ObjectMapper which throws exception at "readerFor".
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to use Mockito/powerMock. Just use a spring boot test.
Something like this:

```
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
public class SomeServiceTest {

    @Autowired
    private SomeService service;

    @Autowired
    private ObjectMapper om;

    @Test
    public void  try_Me(){
        System.out.println(om);
    }
}
```

Adding a some info more to your question. 
If you really want to use mockito for the ObjectMapper you should prepare the mock. If not when calling readerFor(...) the mock returns null by default and later, in the readValue method, you are getting a nullpointer.

A basic preparation for the mock might be:

```
ObjectReader or = Mockito.mock(ObjectReader.class);
Mockito.when(or.readValue(Mockito.anyString())).thenReturn(new instance of your object);
Mockito.when(mapper.readerFor(User.class)).thenReturn(or);
```